# Windows Assembly Hello World

Tags: windows, assembly, intel

The little time I became interested in atraz assembly. Nasm first started with Linux ... I did some basic stuff, but wanted to do in Windows. Hence googled a bit and saw some things for Dos. But depended on emulators. I want to program for Windows 8 64-bit Intel, but everything I search for Windows redirects to Dos ...

In linux to do is interrupt `int 80h`, `int 21h` in Dos, Windows I have no idea how to get a code!

One Hello World and an assembler has helped ...

Comment: thank you! I have to get Link.exe without installing Visual Studio?

Comment: basically, you need to use the win32 api which provides a bunch of functions provided by windows kernel, ntoskrnl.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.friedspace.com/assembly/intro.php).

```
include '%fasminc%/win32ax.inc'

.code

  start:
        invoke  MessageBox,HWND_DESKTOP,"Hello World!","Win32 Assembly",MB_OK
        invoke  ExitProcess,0

.end start
```

Comment: Thanks ! how to make an executable with fasm?

Comment: fasm can emit executables directly.

Comment: got it! and if I want to do without a GUI, ie printing the text in cmd.